# Ошибка в регулярном выражении по номеру телефона

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
$phone = "";
if(isset($_POST['telephone'])) {
    $phone = $_POST['telephone'];
    if(mb_strlen($phone) >= 1) {
        if(!preg_match($phone, '/^\d[\d\(\)\ -]{4,14}\d+$/')) {
            $errors[] = 'Некорректный номер телефона.';
        }
    }
} else {
    $errors[] = 'Невозможно найти номер телефона. Введите данные заново.';
}
```

Ввожу вот такой номер '787487246242'. В результате показывается сообщение 'Некорректный номер телефона.' В чём ошибка? Неправильное регулярное выражение?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php
Ты перепутал аргументы местами в preg_match, сначала регулярное выражение, потом строку, в которой ищем совпадения